# How to send files with filepond?

Tags: php, filepond

I'm using filepond (https://pqina.nl/filepond/) and I was able to configure the server like:

```php
FilePond.setOptions({
    server: 'https://ultimatewebsolutions.net'
});
```

but when I upload a file on client side (filepond is green showing it is accepted), I can not find it on my server. More over I'd like to have that file attached to a mail which I send to my customers.
I'm using a simple php mail sending script and getting the user info from form fields with the usual POST method: `$_POST['firstname']`, `$_POST['lastname']` etc.

How can I have that uploaded file as an attachment in a mail?

Thank you Guys in advance!

**So as a summary:
I would like to send a file (jpg, png, pdf) as an email attachment using phpMailer and filepond together.**

My php code:

```
$getFilename = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'];
$mail->addAttachment($getFilename, 'attachment.pdf');
```

My js code

```
// Register the plugins
FilePond.registerPlugin(FilePondPluginFileValidateSize);
FilePond.registerPlugin(FilePondPluginFileValidateType);

// Get a reference to the file input element
var inputElement = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');

// create a FilePond instance at the input element location
const pond = FilePond.create( inputElement, {
    maxFiles: 1,
    allowFileSizeValidation: true,
    allowFileTypeValidation: true,
    allowFileEncode: true,
    maxFileSize: '150KB',
    acceptedFileTypes: ['image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'application/pdf']
});

FilePond.setOptions({       
        server: './'
});
```

My html:

```
<input type="file" name="attachment" />
```

Comment: If you're running your PHP logic at the URL you've set to the `server` property then the file is posted there and you should find it in the PHP `$_FILES` array (the name used depends on the file input name).

Comment: Hi @Rik, thank you, but I couldn't find the posted file. 

By the way, I'd like to send that file (uploaded with filepond) with phpMailer.

My php file has the following code:

$getFilename = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'];
$mail->addAttachment($getFilename, 'attachment.pdf');

and I can not find the file. It would be the best solution not to store the file just send as an attachment with phpMailer. How can I do this using filepond?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure why, I would check the apache log and network tab of your dev tools to see if the file is sent.